# Static objects in Service Fabric actors

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

There is a service fabric actor with the following definition which is registered and then unregistered by implementing `IRemindable` interface. This actor has a static dictionary too.

```
[StatePersistence(StatePersistence.None)]
[ActorService(Name = "ProcessorActorService")]
public class ProcessorActor : BaseActor, IRemindable
{
 private static Dictionary<object,object> _myDictionary;

}
```

My understanding is that service fabric creates multiple instances of the same actor if each actor's guid is different at instantiation time. When each actor instance is created the reminder's action adds an object to the dictionary for processing later on.

My expectation/understanding has been such that the dictionary's scope is within the same instantiated actor, but when the next actor's instance comes to life, I realize that the `_myDictionary` has the nodes that were added in another actor! So, it kind of gives the impression that the dictionary is shared among all live instances of the same actor type! Is that a correct understanding or the same already-instantiated actor is called again?!

Since the actor implements `IRemindable` I expect the GC to remove the actor from the cluster after unregistering it but it does not seem to be happening. Is it possible that the static dictionary causes the actor's instance to stick around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's more of a **.Net** issue than a **Service Fabric** issue. As far as I remember, static instances are only collected once the **AppDomain** is collected (usually when the process terminates).

Take a look at [Fundamentals of Garbage Collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/fundamentals) on how and when instances get collected.

Regarding how to maintain state, I suggest you take a look at [Introduction to Service Fabric Reliable Actors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction), it might help you achieve what you want.

**Update**

Also, take a look at [Reliable Actors state management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-state-management).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. Well, I think I should rephrase my question a bit. I am aware of maintaining states in service fabric and actors, specifically, I do not want that static dictionary to be shared among multiple instances of the same actor. So, if actor let's say with the Guid of abcdef123 is activated, would it share that static dictionary with another actor with the guid of cde543? This is something that I do not want to happen.

Comment: Then don't use a static dictionary, use **Service Fabric**'s built-in state mechanisms (i.e. reliable actors). See update for link on state management.

Comment: Do you think whether that static dictionary causes the actor's instance to linger around? Does it have an impact on the lifetime of the actor?

Comment: Don't think so, the actor is a regular instance not a static one, only the static "portion" is kept around

Comment: One interesting thing that I saw was that I used Autofac to wire up services in an actor. One of the services was defined as a singleton and that instance was used over and over in every subsequent actor instantiation!

Comment: If used the **Service Locator** anti-pattern, requesting instances directly from a static root of the container instead of using constructor injection, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

> My understanding is that service fabric creates multiple instances of the same actor if each actor's guid is different at instantiation time.

This is correct. Every new ID generates a new instance of the Actor.

---

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static):

> Use the static modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object.

When you declare `private`**`static`**`Dictionary<object,object> _myDictionary;` as **static** you are telling to the ***CLR*** that the field does not belong to an instance of that object but to the type definition, in this case it generates a single instance that belongs to the Actor type and not the the objects created and destroyed by the runtime.

The correct way to save the actor state is using the state manager, like this:

```
[StatePersistence(StatePersistence.Persisted)]
class MyActor : Actor, IMyActor
{
  public MyActor(ActorService actorService, ActorId actorId)
    : base(actorService, actorId)
  {
  }

  public Task<int> GetCountAsync()
  {
    return this.StateManager.GetStateAsync<int>("MyState");
  }
}
```

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-access-save-remove-state) explains it in more details.

Comment: Thanks. Please see the question that I raised to Itay. @Diego